# MFC dialog box continue after pressing ok

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I have a custom dialog message box that pops-up when a `edit control` in my main dialog has wrong data.

```
CDlgError dlgError = new CDlgError(this);
dlgError.Create(CDlgError::IDD, this);
dlgError.m_staticMessage.SetWindowTextA("Error message!");
dlgError.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

//more code
```

I want the rest of the code to be executed only after i press an `OK button` in my `CDlgError` pop-up dialog. How can i do that?

Comment: call `DoModal` instead of `ShowWindow`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DoModal` instead of `Create` and `ShowWindow` to show your error dialog. e.g.

```
CDlgError dlgError = new CDlgError(this);
dlgError.m_strMessage = "Error message!";
dlgError.DoModal();
```

As you can see from the code you'll need to pass in the text and THEN set your message label inside `CDlgError::OnInitDialog` because the control won't be initialized before going modal.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a dialog using `Create` which shows a **modalless** dialog(you can click on other parts of application even dialog is open). 
You requirement is for **modal** dialog where you can not click on any part of application until this dialog is closed.
To do this use `DoModal` function instead of create.